# React JS (History.push)

Tags: reactjs

i am new to react
How to i route to another component, I  have using the method "History.push"
Here is my code

```
import {useState} from 'react';
import axios from "axios"
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
const api=axios.create({baseURL:"https://238.235/v1/user/signup"})
const useForm = (initialValues,validate) => {
    const [inputs,setInputs] = useState(initialValues);
    const [errors,setErrors] = useState({});

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const validationErrors = validate(inputs);
        const noErrors = Object.keys(validationErrors).length === 0;
        setErrors(validationErrors);
        if(noErrors){
            console.log("Authenticated",inputs);
            api.post("/",inputs).then(response => {
                console.log(response.data.message);
              console.log(response);
                var message=response.data.message;
                 if (message==="Success") {
                  
                  toast.success(response.data.message +" : "+response.data.messageDescription);  
                  setTimeout(() => {
                    history.push("/auth/login");
                  }, 3000);
                }
                else
                {
                  toast.error(response.data.message +" : " +response.data.messageDescription);  
                }
              })
        }else{
            console.log("errors try again",validationErrors);
        }
        
    }

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        event.persist();
        setInputs(inputs => ({...inputs, [event.target.name]: event.target.value}));
    }

    return {
        handleSubmit,
        handleChange,
        inputs,
        errors
    };
}
```

What i am trying to do is , If message is success i want to redirect to another component,

i am using history.push method.

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share how you are rendering routes in your app, and how this component accesses the `history` object for navigation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use useHistory()

```
        import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

        function HomeButton() {
          let history = useHistory();

          function handleClick() {
            history.push("/home");
          }

          return (
            <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
              Go home
            </button>
          );
        }
```

OR

```
        import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'; 



        export default withRouter(useForm);
```